# Как получить индекс элемента массива

Tags: javascript

я даже не знаю как отредактировать вопрос, что бы разъяснить вам. если бы я не написал бы вопрос а просто искал бы, я бы не понял из предпологаемого дуюликата ничего, потому  что не обратил бы на него внимание...  для мне тот вариант ответа не является ответом.....

```
var wrapperPlayList = document.getElementById('wrapperPlayList'),
        p = document.createElement('p'),
        mus = music[0];


        var music = [
    '../binary/sounds/music/Strangersbynight.mp3',
    '../binary/sounds/music/029 E-Type - Russian lullaby.mp3',
    '../binary/sounds/music/035 Technotronic - This beat is Technotronic.mp3',
    '../binary/sounds/music/037 Radiorama - Desire.mp3',
    '../binary/sounds/music/039 Silent circle - Touch in the night.mp3'
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < music.length; i++) {
        var playList = p.cloneNode(true);

        playList.innerHTML = music[i];

        playList.className = 'playList';

        wrapperPlayList.appendChild(playList);

        playList.addEventListener('click', function () {
        /*
        как мне тут при клике получиь индекс --- playList 
        */  
        })

    }
```

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Comment: По секрету он на сайте уже более года

Comment: Дубликат?))))  Ну если бы я столько понимал, я бы не задавал вопросов....  Ну раз вы так считайте, объясните?

Comment: _Ну раз вы так считайте, объясните?_ - ты в цикле создаешь функции, которые вызываются не сразу, то есть не в момент создания, и хочешь использовать счетчик внутри этих функций. Все то же самое, что и в вопросе дубликате

Comment: Grundy, я JS изучаю, пару тройку месяцев... щас я код пишу на уровне интуиции...  Если бы ты не ответил как ответил, я бы не решил свою проблему...  вспомни себя, когда ты начал писать код...  что все понимание пришло разом....  это я к тому, что если кто то "сырой"  будут искать впрос подобный моему, то ему будет легче найти ответ в моем вопросе

Comment: @Air, на самом деле не легче, потому что ты завуалировал основной вопрос: получение счетчика цикла в асинхронной функции, своей формулировкой

Comment: с вами не соскучишься))))  я уже понял о чем речь...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для определения индекса элемента у массива есть парные функции [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)/[`.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf), отличающиеся направлением поиска, с начала массива или с конца.

А также функция [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), позволяющая искать индекс элемента, удовлетворяющего переданному условию.

---

Небольшие уточнения по задаче:

1. `this` внутри обработчика будет указывать на текущий *playList*
2. `playList.innerHTML` - строка из массива *music*
3. поиск индекса в массиве *music*

Исходя из этого, предоставленный код можно переписать следующим образом:

```
var wrapperPlayList = document.getElementById('wrapperPlayList'),
    p = document.createElement('p'),
    mus = music[0];


var music = [
    '../binary/sounds/music/Strangersbynight.mp3',
    '../binary/sounds/music/029 E-Type - Russian lullaby.mp3',
    '../binary/sounds/music/035 Technotronic - This beat is Technotronic.mp3',
    '../binary/sounds/music/037 Radiorama - Desire.mp3',
    '../binary/sounds/music/039 Silent circle - Touch in the night.mp3'
];

for (var i = 0; i < music.length; i++) {
    var playList = p.cloneNode(true);

    playList.innerHTML = music[i];

    playList.className = 'playList';

    wrapperPlayList.appendChild(playList);

    playList.addEventListener('click', function () {
        /*
        получить индекс можно так
        */  
        var playListIndex = music.indexOf(this.innerHTML);
        /* или так*/
        var playListIndex = music.lastIndexOf(this.innerHTML);
        /* или так*/
        var playListIndex = music.findIndex(el=>el === this.innerHTML);
    })

}
```

---

Но на самом деле все это не нужно.

Достаточно использовать [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) вместо [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) и в качестве индекса можно использовать переменную `i` напрямую в обработчике:

```
var wrapperPlayList = document.getElementById('wrapperPlayList'),
p = document.createElement('p'),
mus = music[0];


var music = [
    '../binary/sounds/music/Strangersbynight.mp3',
    '../binary/sounds/music/029 E-Type - Russian lullaby.mp3',
    '../binary/sounds/music/035 Technotronic - This beat is Technotronic.mp3',
    '../binary/sounds/music/037 Radiorama - Desire.mp3',
    '../binary/sounds/music/039 Silent circle - Touch in the night.mp3'
];

for (let i = 0; i < music.length; i++) {
    var playList = p.cloneNode(true);

    playList.innerHTML = music[i];

    playList.className = 'playList';

    wrapperPlayList.appendChild(playList);

    playList.addEventListener('click', function () {
    /*
      i - и есть нужный индекс.
    */  
    })

}
```

Comment: тоесть получаеться что с помощью `let` создастся что-то типа замыкания на уровни итерации цикла ?

Comment: @Air, не видел этого вопроса.

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, замыкание есть в любом случае, здесь скорее важно как объявлены переменные которые замыкаются. В отличие от `var`, переменные объявленные с помощью `let` или `const` объявляются на уровне блока `{...}`, а не всей функции, таким образом, на каждой итерации цикла будет _новая_ переменная `i`, которая и будет замкнута, а не одна переменная `i` на всю функцию, значение которой во время обработчика будет тем же, что и после окончания цикла.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за розьяснения, я бы недодумался до такого )

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, ссылки на документацию есть в ответе, там более подробно написано

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно создать [замыкание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), в котором хранить этот самый индекс, для этого `addEventListener` надо вынести в отдельную функцию в которою передавать индекс, в следствии чего индекс будет сохраняться в замыкании функции обработчика клика и вы сможете его использовать.

Вот краткий пример :

```js
var music = [
  '../binary/sounds/music/Strangersbynight.mp3',
  '../binary/sounds/music/029 E-Type - Russian lullaby.mp3',
  '../binary/sounds/music/035 Technotronic - This beat is Technotronic.mp3',
  '../binary/sounds/music/037 Radiorama - Desire.mp3',
  '../binary/sounds/music/039 Silent circle - Touch in the night.mp3'
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < music.length; i++) {
    addEventListenerToBtn(i, document.getElementById('btn' + i))
  }
});


function addEventListenerToBtn(index, btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(music[index]);
  });
};
```

```html
<button id="btn0">btn0</button>
<button id="btn1">btn1</button>
<button id="btn2">btn2</button>
<button id="btn3">btn3</button>
<button id="btn4">btn4</button>
```

Вот пример с вашими тегами `p`:

```js
var music = [
  '../binary/sounds/music/Strangersbynight.mp3',
  '../binary/sounds/music/029 E-Type - Russian lullaby.mp3',
  '../binary/sounds/music/035 Technotronic - This beat is Technotronic.mp3',
  '../binary/sounds/music/037 Radiorama - Desire.mp3',
  '../binary/sounds/music/039 Silent circle - Touch in the night.mp3'
];

var wrapperPlayList = document.getElementById('wrapperPlayList'),
  p = document.createElement('p'),
  mus = music[0];

for (var i = 0; i < music.length; i++) {
  var playList = p.cloneNode(true);
  playList.innerHTML = music[i];
  playList.className = 'playList';

  wrapperPlayList.appendChild(playList);

  addEventListenerToP(i, playList);
}

function addEventListenerToP(index, _p) {
  _p.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(music[index]);
  });
};
```

```html
<div id="wrapperPlayList">
</div>
```

Comment: @Air не думал что так сложно будет переделать пример :) Дополнил ответ

Comment: если вам всетаки нужно при клике на `p` получить тот индекс массива, на котором на этот `p` был повешан ивентхендлер, то функция массива вам не поможет , а надо сменить подход, самый елегантный вариант это замыкания

Comment: @Air ну честно говоря ето костыль, да и не работает в том виде в котором вы написали, но почему бы и нет :)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно ещё вот так. С авто генерацией элементов:

```js
var music = [
  '../binary/sounds/music/Strangersbynight.mp3',
  '../binary/sounds/music/029 E-Type - Russian lullaby.mp3',
  '../binary/sounds/music/035 Technotronic - This beat is Technotronic.mp3',
  '../binary/sounds/music/037 Radiorama - Desire.mp3',
  '../binary/sounds/music/039 Silent circle - Touch in the night.mp3'
];

function addEventListenerToBtn(index, btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("Download: " + this.innerHTML + "\n\r" + 
          "His id: " + this.getAttribute("data-id"));
  });
};

function splitName(str) {
  if (typeof str != "undefined") {  
    return str.split("/");
  }
}
    
function createBtn(tracks) {
  if (tracks.length > 0 && tracks) { 
    for (let i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {

      let p = document.createElement('p'),
          track_name = splitName(tracks[i]);

      p.id = "track-" + i;
      p.className += "playList";
      p.setAttribute("data-id", i);
      p.innerHTML = track_name[track_name.length-1];    
      document.body.appendChild(p);
      addEventListenerToBtn(i, document.getElementById("track-" + i));  
    }
  }
}
    
createBtn(music);
```

Comment: @Air исправил кнопки на параграф.

Comment: @Air в таком случае если ни один из нынешних ответов не удовлетворяет вашим требованиям, напишите ответ сами, и отметте его как решение. :)