# Получить индекс объекта, по которому кликнули

Tags: vue.js

Здравствуйте. Есть задача http://prntscr.com/ghpvpq
При клике на количество должно показываться окошко с редактированием количества. Не могу разобраться в том, как в окошко мне вставить нужные данные. Если, например, я кликнул на элемент объекта с индексом 1, как мне в окне отобразить нужные данные именно этого объекта?

Объект строится подобным образом:

```
listProducts: [
                {
                    name: 'Нож складной WENGER Evolution ,"Автобус" ,13 функций, 85 мм.WENGER',
                    checkbox: true,
                    image: require('./assets/product1.png'),
                    price: 400,
                    count: 3,
                    sum: 0
                },
                {
                    name: 'Рюкзак WENGER «NEO»',
                    checkbox: false,
                    image: require('./assets/product2.png'),
                    price: 200,
                    count: 3,
                    sum: 0
                },
                {
                    name: 'Перьевая ручка Waterman Hemisphere Essential, перо: нержавеющая сталь. WATERMAN',
                    checkbox: true,
                    image: require('./assets/product3.png'),
                    price: 600,
                    count: 3,
                    sum: 0
                }
            ],
```

Comment: ох, тут логику надо прорабатывать.
по сути нужно брать this этого элемента на который вы кликнули и подставлять его count

Comment: Да логика то в целом понятно.. Вот со стороны реализации не дойду никак(

Comment: я не силен пока  в  JS  и у меня был такой же вопрос мне ответили просто вот ссылка может пригодится, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706956/Как-получить-индекс-элемента-массива   я выбрал второй вариант ответа  @Grundy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если тебе нужен именно индек объекта, а не сам объект, тогда ты в шаблоне делаешь следующее:

```js
methods: {
  handleClick(index) {
    this.currentProduct = this.products[index];
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <product 
    v-for="(product, index) in products"  
    @click="handleClick(index)"
  />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема собственно, у вас должна быть конструкция отображающая список продуктов, по клику на продукте нужно показывать ваш виджет и передать в него данные:

```
<product-row v-for="product in products" @click="showWidget(product)"/>
<counter v-if="showCounter" :product="product" @close="showCounter=false"/>


methods: {
  showWidget(product) {
    this.currentProduct = product
    this.showCounter = true
  }
}
```