# Как определить индекс элемента коллекции backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Я не очень хорошо знаю Backbone, поэтому вопрос.

Есть элемент коллекции:

```
// Модель данных для основной таблицы
App.Model.BaseRow = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        // Номер по пункту
        NumberOfItem: '',
        // Наименование
        Name: '',
    }
});
```

Есть коллекция этих эелементов:

```
//Список строк для основной таблицы
App.Collection.BaseTableBody = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Model.BaseRow
});
```

И представление для каждой строки

```
App.View.BaseRow = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    },

    tagName: "tr",

    className: "cssClass_BaseTableRow__tr",

    events: {
        "click": "tuggleSubTable",
    },

    template: template("id_BaseRowTemplate__script"),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );

        return this;
    },

    tuggleSubTable: function(e){
        console.log(e);
        // Метод открывает подтаблицу если она не октрыта или закрывает ее если она открыта
        // 1) Проверть открыта ли таблица
        //     2) Да
        //         3) Найти в коллекции подтаблицу и удалить ее из дом, поставить флаг что подтаблица закрыта
        //          this.model.remove....  - что то вроде того наверное
        //     4) Нет
        //         5) Произветсти запро к БД получить данные для подтаблицу
        //         6) Отрендрить подтаблицу поставить флаг что подтаблица открыта
    }

});
```

Мне надо в методе tuggleSubTable узнать по какому индексу в коллекции находится текущий элемент App.View.BaseRow. это нужно для того что бы в коллекцию вставить новую строку ниже текущей.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить индекс элемента массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706956/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: Не решило но позволило мне задуматься над архитектурой, выходит что каждый элемент коллекции App.Model.BaseRow должен содержать в себе указатель на коллекцию в которой находится. Меня это смущает, не портит ли это архитектуру и стоит ли так делать в backbone, может есть способ лучше?