# Javascript, получение адреса ссылки по событию click

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой код:

```
let l = 
document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (k in l){
l[k].onclick = function(){
alert(this.href);
return false;
}
}
```

Он должен вывести адрес ссылки, я получаю undefined. Пробовал ещё так:

```
let l = 
document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (k in l){
l[k].onclick = function(){
alert(l[k].href);
return false;
}
}
```

Результат такой же. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить индекс элемента массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706956/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

Для получения значения атрибута элемента используйте `getAttribute`. В вашем случае, код будет выглядеть так:

```
let l = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (k in l){
  l[k].onclick = function(){
    alert(this.getAttribute('href'));
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Всё прекрасно работает, спасибо вам.

Answer (score 2):

Первый пример и так работает, а во-втором, ты пропустил инициализацию переменной, как и в первом, но в отличии от первого, второй, что бы от заработал надо в место `var` выбрать `let` подробнее [тут ответ Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706956/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)

```js
let l =
  document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (let k in l) {
  l[k].onclick = function() {
    alert(l[k].href);
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://ya.ru">https://ya.ru</a>
<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>
```

Comment: Ну хотя бы в одном ответе не забыли про инициализацию переменной в цикле, однако правильнее наверное все же использовать в обоих случаях не `let`, а `const`

Answer (score 1):

Вполне всё работает:

```js
let l =  document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (k in l) {
  l[k].onclick = function() {    
    console.log(this.href);
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" id="ttt">test</a>
<a href="http://go123ogle.com"  id="tt23t">test2</a>
```

---

возможно ваш код выполняется до загрузки всего документа?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что в данном случае лучше использовать `for..of`

```
for (let anchor of document.getElementsByTagName("a")) {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', doNothing);
}

const doNothing = e => {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('href'));
}
```