# js Как получить элемент для которого применяется onclick по классу в переменную?

Tags: javascript, click

Есть несколько элементов с одним классом, нужно по нажатию на элемент провести некоторые действия и получить в переменную этот элемент.

```
colorSelector = document.getElementsByClassName('colorSelector'); //Считали все элементы с классом для выбора цвета
  for (let i = 0; i < colorSelector.length; i++) { //Идем по каждому элементу
    colorSelector[i].onclick = () => changeColorSelected(colorSelector[i].getAttribute('class').split(' ')[1]); //Передаем элемент по которому нажали
  }
```

Собственно клик я ловлю и применяю нужные свойства. Кстати, скажите, пожалуйста, если я не правильно делаю клик по классу.
**Но вот как мне получить в переменную элемент на который я кликнул?**

Comment: @Air В том, что я не знаю как это сделать. Вот событие выполняется, все ок. Но как мне получить этот элемент в переменную, чтобы дальше еще кое-как с ним работать

Comment: a `colorSelector[i]` это что такое?

Comment: @Igor Это переменная, в которой будет храниться последний элемент с таким классом, но не тот, на которого был клик. То есть, например у меня 3 элемента. Я кликнул на второй элемент, то есть colorSelector[1], но под конец выполнения цикла в colorSelector[i] у меня будет colorSelector[2], хотя кликнул я на colorSelector[1]

Comment: @Air
Это переменная, в которой будет храниться последний элемент с таким классом, но не тот, на которого был клик. То есть, например у меня 3 элемента. Я кликнул на второй элемент, то есть colorSelector[1], но под конец выполнения цикла в colorSelector[i] у меня будет colorSelector[2], хотя кликнул я на colorSelector[1]

Comment: @Gelloiss это точно?

Comment: Да. Это было первое, что я попробовал. После этого около часа гуглил и вот лишь потом задал вопрос

Comment: @Gelloiss нет, это не точно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить индекс элемента массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706956/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: Почитай ответ Grundy в моем вопросе...

Comment: @Igor Точно. Сами посмотрите. В этом коде я добавляю элементу тестовый аттрибут. И он добавляется не тому элементу, по которому был клик, а последнему. https://jsfiddle.net/30fk9jm7/

Comment: @Gelloiss У Вас нарушена причинно-следственная связь.

Comment: Подскажите, тогда как правильно, пожалуйста?
У меня есть несколько цветов. Изначально выбран itemRed. Эта функция должна при клике переключать на тот цвет, на который был клик. + добавлять css класс. Класс я успешно добавляю, но как мне сохранить новый выбранный цвет?

Comment: @Gelloiss Используйте переменную `lastClicked` - см. ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastClicked = null;

colorSelector = document.getElementsByClassName('colorSelector');
for (let i = 0; i < colorSelector.length; i++) {
  colorSelector[i].onclick = function(e) {
    var clicked = this;
    // or
    var clicked = colorSelector[i];
    // or
    var clicked = e.target;

    lastClicked = clicked;
  };
}
```

```js
var colorSelector = document.getElementsByClassName('colorSelector');
for (let i = 0; i < colorSelector.length; i++) {
  colorSelector[i].onclick = function(e) {
    var clicked1 = this;
    // or
    var clicked2 = colorSelector[i];
    // or
    var clicked3 = e.target;

    console.log(clicked1.textContent, clicked2.textContent, clicked3.textContent);
  };
}
```

```css
.colorSelector {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorSelector">A</div>
<div class="colorSelector">B</div>
<div class="colorSelector">C</div>
```

Comment: и в какой переменной после этого у меня будет элемент для которого было применено событие click?
Вы же просто переписали мой код

Comment: @Gelloiss в переменной `clicked`

Comment: @Gelloiss Нажмите в ответе кнопку "Выполнить код" и покликайте на зеленые прямоугольники.

Comment: Внутри функции события onclick это легко сделать, понятное дело. Но мне нужно после функции, а не в самой функции, получить доступ к элементу

Comment: Понимаете, мне не просто в консоль вывести надо. Это я бы не спрашивал)
Мне надо как-то сохранить элемент в переменную, чтобы после выполнения функции клика, я мог продолжить с ним работать. Вот поэтому и есть этот вопрос у меня!

Comment: @Gelloiss Используйте переменную `lastClicked` - см. ответ.